# Pushing data as fast as possible with autobahn websockets

Tags: python, websocket, autobahn

I'm trying to write a websockets app using autobahn to push data as fast as possible from client to server. With both client and server on localhost, I should be getting very high throughput (a native python throughput test gives me > 1 Gbps), however, the best I can get through websockets is 40Mbps.

I just modified the client code from the autobahn echo client example [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/4bf5f2aaa65346b8b9d75547421d5d96ba139cd4/examples/twisted/websocket/echo/client.py).

Here's my code (self.message is a 100kB length string, and MAXDUR is 5 seconds --- I've varied both without success):

```
     def sendData():
        self.sendMessage(self.message,sync=True)
        self.totbytes += len(self.message)
        if duration > MAXDUR:
          self.factory.reactor.callLater(0, end)
          return
        self.factory.reactor.callLater(0, sendData)
```

I've tried sending the message as a long frame using sendMessageFrameData, and with and without sync=True. The fastest I can get is 40Mbps.

Am I hitting websocket limits? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the CPU usage at both ends? It could be a CPU bottleneck.

Comment: Hello Emile, Thanks for the response. Both client and server are on localhost, and taking about 40-60% of one core (it's a quadcore). It cannot be the CPU as I'm easily able to push 100x that using a native python server/client using plain sockets.